# Php problem with variables

Tags: php, class

For example I have 3 files:

First `index.php` with following code :

```
<?php
  include("includes/vars.php");
  include("includes/test.class.php");

  $test = new test();
?>
```

then `vars.php` with following code:

```
<?php
  $data = "Some Data";
?>
```

and last `test.class.php`

```
 <?php
 class test 
{
  function __construct()
  {
    echo $data;
  }
}
?>
```

When I run index.php the `Some Data` value from `$data` variable is not displayed, how to make it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Reading material.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Because of scope. Data is within the global scope and the only thing available within a class are variables and methods within the class scope.

You could do

```
class test 
{
  function __construct()
  {
    global $data;
    echo $data;
  }
}
```

But it is **not** good practice to use global variables within a class.

You could pass the variable into the class via the constructor.

```
class test 
{
  function __construct($data)
  {
    echo $data;
  }
}

$test = new test("test");
```

Comment: Using global variables is considered bad practice in this context.

Comment: Yes. That is exactly what I say. "But it is **not** good practice to use global variables within a class."

Comment: but if to use $GLOBALS[data]? is this good or it can cause problems later?

Comment: @John using global variables within functions or classes can cause problems. What if you're using this global variable within two classes? And one class changes the variable and then the other one wants to read it? The second class now has a different value than he did before, and this can cause problems.

Answer (score 1):

The `echo $data;` tries to echo data from your local variable which is obviously not set.
You should pass the $data to your constructor:

```
    <?php
 class test 
 {
   function __construct($data)
   {
     echo $data;
   }
 }
?>
```

And it will work like this:

```
$test = new test($data);
```

You will have to initialize the global variable $data before instantiating the test object.

Comment: It should resolve your problem...or what is your problem then?

Comment: i will have a lot of variables inside vars.php, and to add them all using : new test(var1, var2...) is not a good option

Comment: You haven't stated that in your question. You can put your variables into an array.

Answer (score 1):

The `$data` isn't in the same scope, that is why it's not available.
If you want data available that are not defined within your class, you can pass the data along.

```
class Test 
{
    function __construct($data)
    {
        echo $data;
    }
}
$oTest = new Test('data');
```

Answer (score 0):

I could suggest you to use globals, but thats quite ugly. I suggest you to use constants instead, as this feels sufficient

```
define('DATA', "Some Data");
```

Another solution is to inject the value into the object

```
class test {
  public function __construct ($data) {
    echo $data;
  }
}
$test = new test($data);
```